# How do I increment a variable every second?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, time, applet

I'm making a cookie clicker like game. What I'm stuck on is incrementing a variable that I will be using every second. This variable will be the currency of my game.

There will be two ways that I will get this currency

1. Clicking on a picture
2. Letting the game run

I'm able to accomplish the first method, but what I'm stuck on is the second one where I need allow the variable to increase every 1 second. I also need the the counter for the currency to be constantly updated everytime there is a button click.

What I tried was the sleep method, but that would stop the program from updating when the user click the button. Would I have to use more than 1 thread to accomplish this?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Timers are intended for this type of thing. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html.

Comment: Which GUI are you using?

Comment: I am using the JCreator Java Applet. Should there be a problem?

Comment: I meant, are you using AWT, Swing, JavaFX...?

Comment: If you want to do it yourself `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` could be useful for the counter.

Answer (score 1):

As someone suggested use a timer, 
Then you'll need a seperate thread which updates the seconds / gui, since you don't want your main thread to get stuck.

1. Button is pressed
2. Something like this might suit you?

> ```
> void OnButtonPress(){
> Thread t = new Thread(
> new Runnable(){
>     @Override
>     void run(){
>     //timer tics here
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

Don't forget to start the thread where appropriate 
Happy coding!

Comment: I have a question, so if I want the method OnButtonPress(), then when it hit a certain requirement, then I can just call OnButtonPress(), and then it will create a new thread and do it own thing?

Comment: yes, ofCourse, but just to be clear you don't need a method, you can start a new thread anywhere, when t.start() is called, that threads runnables run() method will be called. you have hit a point where you need two things two happen simultaneously, so you need two threads, each thread is independent from each other. note the run() method will be called once on start() so you'll need a loop inside there,